# Journals in statistical learning / machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Can you please name some major and minor journals publishing articles in the field of statistical learning / machine learning.

Comment: I've voted to close as this isn't a question on topic for the site as [per the FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and it is a list question. There may be a limited number of machine learning *specific* journals, but if you want journals who publish research and/or applied applications related to machine learning the list would likely be in the hundreds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some influential journals in machine learning:

- [IEEE TPAMI](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/tpami)
- [Journal of Machine Learning Research](http://jmlr.org/)
- [Neural Computation](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/loi/neco)
- [Neurocomputing](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/neurocomputing/)
- [Pattern Recognition Letters](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/pattern-recognition-letters/)

Note that in machine learning some big conferences are considered equivalent to journal publications (NIPS, KDD), similar to computer science. I don't know if this trend also occurs in stats, I think not.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot up vote the answer. Looks like I am not allowed to do so.